# Flatten Domain Class To ViewModel When Source Is Complex

Tags: mapping, valueinjecter

I am using ValueInjecter to map domain classes to my view models. My domain classes are complex. To borrow an example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824836/how-do-i-create-a-custom-value-injection-to-map-my-entity-to-my-view-model-atte/12841941#12841941):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Zip { get; set; }
}

//  VIEW MODEL 

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; } 
}
```

I have looked at FlatLoopInjection, but it expects the view model classes to be prefixed with nested domain model type like so:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int AddressId { get; set; }
   public string AddressCity { get; set; }
   public string AddressState { get; set; }
   public string AddressZip { get; set; }
```

}

The OP in the linked question altered his view models to match the convention expected by FlatLoopInjection. I don't want to do that.
How can I map my domain model to the original unprefixed view model? I suspect that I need to override FlatLoopInjection to remove the prefix, but I am not sure where to do this. I have looked at the source for FlatLoopInjection but I am unsure if I need to alter the Match method or the SetValue method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need flattening, add the map first:

```
Mapper.AddMap<Person, PersonViewModel>(src =>
{
    var res = new PersonViewModel();
    res.InjectFrom(src); // maps properties with same name and type
    res.InjectFrom(src.Address);
    return res;
});
```

and after that you can call:

```
var vm = Mapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(person);
```

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Although this works, in practice my models are more complex, sometimes comprised of more than just a one sub object so that mapping contains a fair amount of manual code to map the sub classes. I may try creating an injection that maps properties with same name and type even if the source properties are nested. Some of the code in FlatLoopInjection looks promising for this.

Comment: keep in mind that you can call `Mapper.Map` inside `AddMap`

Comment: Thanks. I wondered about that and was going to try it. Thanks for creating this Mapper.